# RStudio with node reverse proxy not working

Tags: json, node.js, proxy, rstudio, reverse-proxy

If I use nginx as the reverse proxy for RStudio, it works great following the instructions on https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552326-Running-RStudio-Server-with-a-Proxy?mobile_site=true

However if I write my proxy using node http proxy, I get an error with "code 6 Invalid json-rpc request".

I am using express and http-proxy. Users with similar issues claim that node middleware modifies the JSON request.

Comment: did you fix this?

Comment: have you found a workaround? thanks